# Simple php in wordpress widget

Tags: php, widgets, forms

I am trying to calculate with simple maths but I cant get the following form make the calculations and output the results. Unfortunately I am a newbie. What's wrong?

```
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'register_my_dashboard_widget' );
function register_my_dashboard_widget() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
        'net_profit_widget',
        'Net Profit Calculator',
        'net_profit_widget_display'
    );

}

function net_profit_widget_display() {

    $subrice = $_POST['subrice'];
    $subnumb = $_POST['subnumb'];
    $payperc = "2.9";
    $paystan = "0.3";
    $netprof = "N/A";
    $expense = "N/A";

    if (!$subrice="" || !$subnumb="") {
        die("Please fill in all the required information!");
        //exit();
    } else {
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $expense = $_POST[subrice] * (($payperc / 100) + $paystan);
            $netprof = ($_POST[subprice] - $expense) * $_POST[subnumb];
        }
    }
?>

    <div style="color: #777;">Paypal fee per transaction: 2.9% + $0.3</div><br>
    <form class="netcalc" method="POST" action="">
        <label for="sub-price">Subscription Price($)</label><input id="sub-price" type="text" value="<?php $_POST['subrice']; ?>">
        <br><label for="total-subs">Subscriptions Sold</label><input  id="total-subs" type="text" value="<?php $_POST['subname']; ?>" >
        <br><br><div><span class="expenses-label">Expenses</span><span class="expenses-output">$<?php echo $expense; ?></span></div>
        <div><span class="net-profit-label">Net Profit</span><span class="net-profit-output">$<?php echo $netprof; ?></span></div>
        <br><br><input id="submit" class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Calculate"></input>
    </form>
<?php }
```

?>

Comment: It would be a far better idea to use Javascript for this simple math than it is to hit the server with a new page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'register_my_dashboard_widget' );
function register_my_dashboard_widget() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
        'net_profit_widget',
        'Net Profit Calculator',
        'net_profit_widget_display'
    );

}

function net_profit_widget_display() {

    $subPrice = 0;
    $subnumb = 0;
    if (array_key_exists('subprice', $_POST) !== false) {
        $subPrice = $_POST['subprice'];
    }
    if (array_key_exists('subnumb', $_POST) !== false) {
        $subnumb = $_POST['subnumb'];
    }


    $payperc = "2.9";
    $paystan = "0.3";
    $netprof = "N/A";
    $expense = "N/A";



    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if ($subPrice === false || $subnumb === false ) {
            die("Please fill in all the required information!");
        } else {
            $expense = $subPrice * (($payperc / 100) + $paystan);
            $netprof = ($subPrice - $expense) * $subnumb;
        }
    }
?>

    <div style="color: #777;">Paypal fee per transaction: 2.9% + $0.3</div><br>
    <form class="netcalc" method="POST" action="#">
        <label for="sub-price">Subscription Price($)</label><input name="subprice" id="sub-price" type="text" value="<?php echo $subPrice; ?>">
        <br><label for="total-subs">Subscriptions Sold</label><input name="subnumb" id="total-subs" type="text" value="<?php echo $subnumb; ?>" >
        <br><br><div><span class="expenses-label">Expenses</span><span class="expenses-output">$<?php echo $expense; ?></span></div>
        <div><span class="net-profit-label">Net Profit</span><span class="net-profit-output">$<?php echo $netprof; ?></span></div>
        <br><br><input id="submit" class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Calculate"></input>
    </form>
<?php }
```

Comment: Omar thank you very much for your answer. Would you mind explaining what you did here as I am highly interested in learning php?

Comment: By the way there is a problem. When it comes to `$netprof = ($subPrice - $expense) * $subnumb;` it seems it doesn't calculate the `$subnumb`. I echo'ed the `$subnumb` and is being displayed correctly but when it comes to the equation it just ignores it. Why does this happen?

Comment: @ArgGeo Dear Arg, I can't explain the working of this PHP script here because this website is for WordPress related issues and this problem is hardly WordPress related. Post this working script on stackoverflow.com and you'll surely get very good explanations of the running of this script.

Comment: @ArgGeo The script is running perfectly fine on my side for both expense and netprof. What input values do you enter in Subscription price and Subscription sold?

Comment: Oh, I understand, nevermind. Well, I enter 9.99 in subscription price and 2 in subscriptions sold. I still can't get the correct result. It only calculates expenses for 1 subscription.

Comment: @ArgGeo Then there is something wrong with your formulas. You might want to review them. Try using this expense formula: `$expense = ( ($subPrice * ($payperc / 100)) + $paystan) * $subnumb;`

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks again for your valuable help Omar!